# how to port intel based linux application to ARM platform

Tags: arm

I need to port a few Intel based Linux applications to the ARM platform. Can anybody tell me
what are the best cross compiling tools for this project?

Thanks.

Comment: CodeSourcery ARM toolchain. Rest of the question is too vague.

Comment: Sorry for my quick and unclear question. I know there are several tools that we can use to cross compile an application for ARM platform. For example, openEmbedded and bitbake is one option and codeSoucery is another. I also find an Eclipse plugin for cross compiling purpose for ARM platform. I am not sure which one to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Ubuntu Linux host you may use just a default ARM toolchain:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

To build your linux applications you just have to use the same tools, 
but prefixed with:

`arm-linux-gnueabi-`

For example, to build a simple helloworld.c:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o helloworld helloworld.c
```

You can also set some ARM-related flags to optimize your build or to specify your target platform. Here some examples of important ARM GCC flags, depending on the target ARM CPU:

```
ARM 11:    -mtune=arm1136j-s -mfpu=vfp -mfp=vfp -march=armv6 -mfloat-abi=softfp
Cortex A8: -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8
Cortex A9: -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp
```

Note, that your target ARM CPU may require another options, for example if it doesn't support NEON instructions. GCC compilers from CodeSourcery may also need another options set - just read the docs from CodeSourcery for a particular GCC version.

Comment: Thanks psiHodelia. Your answer really helps clarifying some of my doubts. I will try the codeSoucery one.